# How to manipulate the trainable tensor multiply operation in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tend to build a model, that one input of the model is a tensor with the shape of `(?, 29, 64)`. 
This is the definition in my model's code:

> history_topics = Input(shape=(29, 64, ), name = 'history')

And then I have transposed it to a new tensor with the shape of `(?,64,29)`

> history_topics_trans = Lambda(lambda x:
>   K.tf.transpose(x,perm=[0,2,1]))(history_topics)

And after that, I want to initialize a new trainable tensor called `da`, with the shape of `(5, 64)`, and multiply `da` to `history_topics_trans` to get 
a new tensor with the shape of `(?,5,29)`.

So how to realize it ? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Yanan Chen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `Dense` layer for this. If you don't need the bias term, you can set `use_bias=False`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
K = keras.backend

history_topics = keras.layers.Input(shape=(29, 64), name='history')
history_topics_proj = keras.layers.Dense(5, use_bias=False)(history_topics)
history_topics_trans = keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda x: tf.transpose(x, perm=[0,2,1]))(history_topics_proj)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[history_topics], outputs=[history_topics_trans])

model.summary()
```

Here's the output:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
history (InputLayer)         [(None, 29, 64)]          0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 29, 5)             320
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_2 (Lambda)            (None, 5, 29)             0
=================================================================
Total params: 320
Trainable params: 320
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

You can see the weights of a `Dense` layer like this:

```
dense_layer = keras.layers.Dense(5, use_bias=False)
... # use the layer, so its weights get constructed
[weights] = dense_layer.get_weights()
```

If you want bias terms, just don't set `use_bias=False`. In this case, `get_weights()` will return both the weights matrix and the bias vector:

```
dense_layer = keras.layers.Dense(5)
... # use the layer, so its weights get constructed
[weights, bias] = dense_layer.get_weights()
```

A Keras layer is built lazily, the first time it is actually used. If you try to get the weights before they are constructed, you will get an empty list. To force the weights to be created, you can call the layer on some data, or just call the `build()` method directly:

```py
dense_layer.build(input_shape=[None, None, 64])
```

Note that the `input_shape` argument should be called `batch_input_shape` because it includes the full shape of the input, including the batch dimension.

The `get_weights()` method returns a NumPy array. If you prefer to get symbolic tensors, for example to use the weights in your model directly, you should use the `variables` instance variable instead:

```
>>> dense_layer.variables
[<tf.Variable 'kernel_5:0' shape=(64, 5) dtype=float32>]
```

Comment: Thanks.   history_topics_proj = Dense(5, use_bias=False, name='proj')(history_topics)

Comment: What is the shape of the dense layer named 'proj', is it a tensor with shape of (64, 5) ?

Comment: Hi Yanan. The layer itself does not have a shape. It is an object that contains zero or more weights, each of which has a shape. A `Dense` layer has a weights matrix (in this case, 64x5) and sometimes a bias vector (in this case, none, since use_bias=False). Moreover, when the layer processes some inputs, it outputs something, which has a shape. In this case the input is 3D, with shape [m, 29, 64], where m is the batch size. The output is the result of the matrix multiplication of this input with the weights matrix, for each instance in the batch, and for each topic. Output shape: [m, 29, 5].